# git ignore permission for everyone

Tags: git, chmod

I have a git repo, few of us work on it on different computers, some on windows, some linux.

Problem is file permissions get changed, some times for web server configuration. So they show up in git diff. I ignored filemode changes with command

```
git config core.filemode false
```

But that need to be done for every user, every time we deploy code on a web server, etc..

Is there anyway we can tell ignore permissions for this repo. Something like a .gitattributes file, so that every time some one clone this repo, any changes in file permissions are ignored with out running "git config core.filemode false" ?